# How to get values of chart from code behind c# asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, google-visualization

How to get values of chart from code behind c# asp.net web form, below is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
     google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});     
  </script>
 <script language = "JavaScript">
     function drawChart() {
        // Define the chart to be drawn.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Home Type', 'Total', 'Pending', 'Closed'],
           ['one', 20, 10, 10],
           ['two',  15, 6, 8],
           ['three',  5, 1, 4],
           ['four',  5, 1, 8],
           ['five',  5, 1, 4],
           ['six',  20, 10, 10],
           ['seven',  15, 6, 8],
           ['eight',  5, 1, 3],
           ['nine',  5, 1, 8],
           ['ten',  5, 1, 12],
        ]);

        var options = {colors: ['#257ec2', '#f1565a', '#2ab691'], legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },chartArea:{
left:5,
top: 20,
width: '100%',
height: '370',
 }};  

        // Instantiate and draw the chart.
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('container'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
     }
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  </script>
```

below is my html

```
<div id = "container" style = "height: 490px;"></div>
```

i am not getting any idea to get dynamic from code behind c#

Comment: jQuery ajax call?

Comment: Why would you get the value *from the chart*? You've got the data declared in your JavaScript already. Why not just pass that to the server side?

Comment: numbers i want to take from code behind web method. @Izzy

Comment: store the values in an asp:HiddenField using a js function on client side before the postback

Comment: Please can you paste code. @B.Lec

Comment: See afzalulh answer from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250758/setting-a-value-to-a-hiddenfield-in-asp-net-4-5

Comment: this is not related chart related answer. @B.Lec

Comment: Sorry I missread you don't need to retrieve values from the chart but to set them.

Comment: Please can you update you answer here in stack over flow. @B.Lec

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but instead of putting your `<script/>` in your aspx, you have to inject the js block in the aspx.cs using 
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Something like that :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    regiterAdsScript();  
}

public void regiterAdsScript()
{
    // Define the name and type of the client script on the page.
    String csName = "ButtonClickScript";
    Type csType = this.GetType();
    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    // Check to see if the client script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName))
    {
        StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
        csText.AppendLine("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> ");
        csText.AppendLine("     google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});");
        csText.AppendLine("</script>");
        csText.AppendLine("<script language =  <\"JavaScript\">");
        csText.AppendLine("     function drawChart() {");
        csText.AppendLine("        // Define the chart to be drawn.");
        csText.AppendLine("        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([");
        csText.AppendLine("           ['Home Type', 'Total', 'Pending', 'Closed'],");
        csText.AppendLine("           ['one', 20, 10, 10],");
        csText.AppendLine("           ['two',  15, 6, 8],");
        csText.AppendLine("           ['three',  5, 1, 4],");
        csText.AppendLine("           ['four',  5, 1, 8],");
        csText.AppendLine("           ['five',  5, 1, 4],");
        csText.AppendLine("           ['six',  20, 10, 10],");
        csText.AppendLine("           ['seven',  15, 6, 8],");
        csText.AppendLine("           ['eight',  5, 1, 3],");
        csText.AppendLine("           ['nine',  5, 1, 8],");
        csText.AppendLine("           ['ten',  5, 1, 12],");
        csText.AppendLine("        ]);");
        csText.AppendLine("        var options = {colors: ['#257ec2', '#f1565a', '#2ab691'], legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },chartArea:{left:5,top: 20,width: '100%',height: '370', }};");
        csText.AppendLine("        // Instantiate and draw the chart.");
        csText.AppendLine("        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('container'));");
        csText.AppendLine("        chart.draw(data, options);");
        csText.AppendLine("     }");
        csText.AppendLine("     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);");
        csText.AppendLine("</script>");

        //cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString());
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(csType, csName, csText.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not getting any output from you code and also i am getting error in this line:     string adsLink = ads_link(loc);. @B. Lec

Comment: Edited, use `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, error line is a copy/pasta error.If it doesn't work check if the 2 <script/> tags are rendered in your browser (hit F12)